# To Regex Pandoc Tables

Tags: regular-expression, perl, latex

Minimum Data to regex

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

-------------------------------------------------------------
A           B       C               D
Header      Aligned Aligned         Aligned
----------- ------- --------------- -------------------------
First       row     12.0            Example of a row that
                                    spans multiple lines.

Second      row     5.0             Here's another one. Note
                                    the blank line between
                                    rows.
-------------------------------------------------------------

Table: Here's the caption. It, too, may span
multiple lines.

\section{Lorem Ipsun}
Hello world!

-------------------------------------------------------------
A           B       C               D
Header      Aligned Aligned         Aligned
----------- ------- --------------- -------------------------
First       row     12.0            Example of a row that
                                    spans multiple lines.

Second      row     5.0             Here's another one. Note
                                    the blank line between
                                    rows.
-------------------------------------------------------------

Table: Here's the caption. It, too, may span
multiple lines.

\end{document}
```

Desired output

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
A           B       C               D
Header      Aligned Aligned         Aligned
----------- ------- --------------- -------------------------
First       row     12.0            Example of a row that
                                    spans multiple lines.

Second      row     5.0             Here's another one. Note
                                    the blank line between
                                    rows.
-------------------------------------------------------------

Table: Here's the caption. It, too, may span
multiple lines.

-------------------------------------------------------------
A           B       C               D
Header      Aligned Aligned         Aligned
----------- ------- --------------- -------------------------
First       row     12.0            Example of a row that
                                    spans multiple lines.

Second      row     5.0             Here's another one. Note
                                    the blank line between
                                    rows.
-------------------------------------------------------------

Table: Here's the caption. It, too, may span
multiple lines.
```

I want extract all tables from LaTeX document.

### Pseudocode

1. match >7 of "-" in a row and until everything until "Table:". Include the line with "Table:" but not not anything after that line.
2. iterate 1) until the end of the file

### My attempt

The first step

```
[-]{10,777}$
```

and to include now everything except word "Table:"

```
((?!Table:).)*$
```

and include finally everything from line with "Table:"

```
^(?=.*?\Table:\b)
```

All combined

```
[-]{10,777}$((?!Table:).)*$^(?=.*?\Table:\b)
```

which cannot work. There is something wrong but I do not know what.

**How can you regex such an environment well in Perl?**

Comment: Use `pandoc` to parse the LaTeX file, then select the interesting tables in the result, then use `pandoc` again to convert the result back to LaTeX.

Comment: 1) This is not a LaTeX file 2) please [edit] and show us your desired output. Why do you both not want _and_ want the caption?

Comment: @Icd047 I want to extract all tables. I am not aware that you can as efficient parsin directly with Pandoc as you can with terdon's regex.

Comment: @terdon This is a pre-form of the tex file. Here, I am thinking the automation of different elements in note taking and presentation. The final output will be eventually a LaTeX file but, at this point, everything is little simplified http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245572/13173

Comment: @Costas Good alternative! I think wrapping this command in a function where looping lines is an option. However, this approach may not be so extensible as the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll edit this if you update the question but I *think* you're looking for something like this:

```
perl -007lne '@F=(/-{7,}.*?Table:.*?\n(?=\n)/gsm); print join "\n", @F' file.tex
```

#### Explanation

- `-007` : slurp the entire file
- `-lne` : add a new `l`ine to each `print` call, process the input file, and run the script given by `-e`.
- `@F=(/pattern/gsm)` : save all matches of `pattern` in the array `@F`. The `g` turns on global matching, the `s` makes `.` match newlines and the `m` causes the match operator to match across multiple lines.
- `-{7,}.*?Table:.*?\n(?=\n)` : match 7 or more `-`, then anything until the 1st `Table:` (`.*?Table:)`, then anything until the first two consecutive newlines (`.*?\n(?=\n)`). I'm using a lookahead only to avoid printing both newlines.
- `print join "\n", @F` : print each element of the array `@F`, separating them with newlines.

Comment: I think you understood me correctly. I added the desired output above. Yes, I want the caption which ends when a new empty line.

Comment: @Masi thanks for the update. OK, then this should be pretty much what you were looking for. The important points are i) `X{N,}` will match `X` `N` or more times; ii) you need the `m` switch if you want the match operator to match across multiple lines and the `s` switch if you want `.` to match a newline; iii) you don't need to use `$`, `.*` will match until the end of the line unless you tell it not to; iv) `$()` makes no sense in a regex.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n '/-\{10,777\}/,/^\s*Table:/p' LaTeX.doc
```

If you wants newline after each table:

```
sed -n '/^\s*Table:/G;/-\{10,777\}/,/^\s*Table:/p' LaTeX.doc
```

or

```
sed '/-\{10,777\}/,/^\s*Table:/! d;/^\s*Table:/G' LaTeX.doc
```